# What is residual interaction physically?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, interactions

In any nuclei, if it is even-even or odd-even we can determine ground state spin and parity just by single particle shell model. But if in a odd-odd nuclei, we consider residual interaction to determine ground state.How can one define this residual interaction physically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [reference](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/odd-odd-nuclei) a residual interaction hamiltonian between proton and neutron is used, and the form is "chosen" for simplicity in order to fit the $Tm_{168}^*$ nucleus properties.

In general  one expects that the strong force that holds nuclei together, is a spill-over or [residual force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) from the quantum chromodynamics strong force (QCD) between the quarks that make up the nucleons. The shell model has been successful in modeling the energy levels of nuclei, where it fails a residual potential is fitted to the data, as far as I can see.